# Loop not being entered

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Why the cursor is not going in for loop at all? Please refer the below code

```
public static void searchElement(int[] arr, int searchElement){
        int n = arr.length-1;
        int j= n/2; 
        int temp =0;

        for(int i=0; i==j; i++) {
          System.out.println(searchElement);
          System.out.println(arr[j]);............

.....
}
```

Comment: i==j ?  loop condition check.

Comment: `arr.length == 0` most probably.

Comment: Print out the value of `j`.

Comment: In case wher arr.length!=1 condition `i==j` always false. Looks like you write wrong case condition

Comment: Just use `for (int element : arr)`... Why do you need `i`, `j`, `n`, or `temp`?

Comment: you probably meant i<j instead of i==j and arr[i] instead of arr[j]

Answer (score 1):

i==j will never be true unless n is 0 or 1.

`0/2 = 0`

`1/2 = 0.5` but since it's an Integer and not a double, it equals 0.